# Using MvvmCross, how do I get an "opposite" binding for a bool?

Tags: mvvmcross

In my particular application, I would like the background to be Transparent, i.e., Transparent = true, when the IsSelected is false. I suspect I have to write a Converter, but perhaps there is an easier way?

```
set.Bind(selectedBox).For(v => v.Transparent).To(vm => vm.IsSelected).OneWay();
```

Looks like there is a WithConversion<...> possibility. Perhaps I need a NotValueConverter? Hard to believe this is not already implemented somewhere....

**Update.** I added the following to my Core

```
public class NotConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, bool>
{
    protected override bool Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !value;
    }

    protected override bool ConvertBack(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}
```

but it does not seem to be picked up by the sweep and

```
set.Bind(selectedBox).For(v => v.Transparent).To(vm => vm.IsSelected).WithConversion("Not").OneWay();
```

does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converters need to end with `ValueConverter` to be picked up automatically by MvvmCross. You can also use a generic type to use `WithConversion`.

```
set.Bind(selectedBox).For(v => v.Transparent).To(vm => vm.IsSelected).WithConversion<NotConverter>().OneWay();
```

I thought that "Not" was a built-in converter, and i've used it on Android, but i can't find anything on this so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this, so I started looking through the MvvmCross code. On Android, you can do something like:

```
app:MvxBind="Enabled !SomeBoolean"
```

which works, but it's actually the `MvxInvertedValueCombiner` that's doing this, not any `ValueConverter`. So in fluent form this should do the trick:

```
set.Bind(selectedBox).For(v => v.Transparent).ByCombining(new MvxInvertedValueCombiner(), vm => vm.IsSelected)
```

I've actually never used it in that way, but it seems to work. Furthermore it appears that the value combiner is applied before any value converter, so let's say you were tired of that `MvxInvertedVisibilityValueConverter`, you could do something like this on Android:

```
app:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(!HideMe)"
```